# How to make more tick marks appear in graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want more tick marks appear in graph. For example, if I do this: `plot(1:1000)`, I get the following:

[image: original]

How to make more tick marks appear as shown at the X-axis of the following figure?
[image: wanted]

I want to do the same for Y-axis. Customizing this is not documented.

Comment: What did you do for the X-axis?

Comment: The [documentation explains](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html) how to modify the [tick locations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_XTick) and [tick labels](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_XTickLabel)

Comment: @excaza i have read it but couldnt find my answer. I am trying to  add just more tick lines between two labels as I shown in the question.

Comment: @mpaskov notice the more tick lines between labels on the x-axis

Comment: You already did it for the X-axis, with some command, modifying the command for Y-axis did not work?

Comment: @mpaskov I did that to x-axis with paint. I want to do this with matlab

Comment: My bad it looked like it was done in matlab, impresive paint skills. Well @rayryeng solution is a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MATLAB 2016a or later you can use the Ruler properties:

```
plot(1:1000);
ax = gca;
ax.YMinorTick = 'on';
ax.YAxis.MinorTickValuesMode = 'manual'; % prevents MATLAB form update it
tick_gap = ax.YAxis.TickValues(2)-ax.YAxis.TickValues(1);
minor_tick_no = 5;
minor_gap = tick_gap/minor_tick_no;
ax.YAxis.MinorTickValues = ax.YAxis.TickValues(1)+minor_gap:...
    minor_gap:ax.YAxis.TickValues(end);
```

[image: minor_tick]

And the same for the `ax.XAxis` property.

Comment: Thank you.This is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

For more recent versions of MATLAB you simply grab the axes and change the `YMinorTick` property to `'on'`:

```
plot(1:1000);
ax = gca;
ax.YMinorTick = 'on';
```

For older versions, you have to grab the axes using the `set` function:

```
plot(1:1000);
set(gca, 'YMinorTick', 'on');
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: Sir, this is almost what i want but is this possible that I give ,say 5, tick lines to appear between all points instead of letting matlab to decide that